# Gson - How do you store properties and values

Tags: java, gson

How do I go about storing the values for "id" and "name" as `HashMap<Integer, String>` respectively?

Currently, dumping out `pseudoStations` gives me `[{"id":0,"name":"London"}, {"id":1,"name":"Nottingham"}]`. Iterating through would just give me a `JsonObject` for each list element.

**Main Class**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("stations.json"));
        StationManager sm = gson.fromJson(br, StationManager.class);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            closeBufferedReader(br);
        }
    }
}
```

**Station Manager Class**

```
public class StationManager {
    @SerializedName("pseudoStations")
    @Expose
    private List<JsonObject> pseudoStations = null;

    public void setPseudoStations(List<JsonObject> pseudoStations) {
        this.pseudoStations = pseudoStations;
    }
}
```

**stations.json**

```
{
  "pseudoStations":[
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "London"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Nottingham"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you think you need a `HashMap<Integer, String>` or how that would be able to store your `id` and `name` key-value pairs. Create a POJO with two fields corresponding to those names. And change your `pseudoStations` to be a `List` of that POJO.

Comment: Create a Class Station with properties name and id and map the Json to it the class create a new Instance of the class for each station in your Json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the List of JSONObject from StationManager and add the data to HashMap.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, String> output = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("stations.json"));
        StationManager sm = gson.fromJson(br, StationManager.class);
        List<JsonObject> listOfObjs = sm.getPseudoStations();
        for(JsonObject obj: listOfObjs){
            output.put(obj.getInt("id"), obj.getString("name"));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            closeBufferedReader(br);
        }
    }
}
```